# Visio services in WSS 3.0

Tags: wss-3.0, visio

Do we have Visio services in WSS 3.0 ?
I mean, do WSS 3.0 provide any kind of support for VISIO ?

Answer (score 2):

As [Microsoft describe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee518662.aspx#Visio), [Visio services](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee663485.aspx) is a new feature of the 2010 version of SharePoint.

What is your requirement ? Maybe there will be alternatives...

Comment: And then only Server Enterprise

Comment: I mean if in a Document Library in one of my WSS 3.0 sites i have a Visio file uploaded. Now, can i open and edit the file directly in the browser, in the same way as i can do for excel or word documents.

Comment: yes you can, but why don't you try by yourself ? It may, however, depend on the version of Visio.